# Efficient way to read key-value pairs for frequent lookups

Tags: java, design-patterns, osgi, aem

I'm storing a few properties(KV pairs) in a hierarchical db(`JCR`). As part of business logic, i have to lookup these key-value pairs very frequently and each time i have to call a method which goes and retrieves the persisted value.

I'm working on a `CMS` called `AEM` and all these key-value pairs are authored using a component and stored as `JCR` properties. Presently i've written an `OSGi` service which will go to that node and retrieve the value corresponding to the key and this method gets invoked several several times. Instead of making repeated calls to the service method to retrieve these values, can you suggest an efficient way to do this? `OSGi` auto-wiring?

Comment: Can you not cache the values in a HashMap locally and lookup from it?

Comment: are you referring to something like this .. http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-a-simple-in-memory-cache-in-java-lightweight-cache/

Comment: any comments on why this question has been downvoted?

Comment: [Ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/) is a popular solution, if it turns out you need something more robust than a HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest you to thing twice if you really need to get rid of (or decrease) node properties reading. Do you have performance issues because of this reading or you have another important reason?

If you still wanna to mess with it, I would suggest you next configuration:

- You have a Cache Component, which contains this map with all key-value pairs.
- You have Listener, which listens to node's change, which contains this data, and invalidates cache on such event (so cache will be rebuilt next time it accessed).

There is a great variety of cache implementations, or you can use simple map for this.

Comment: @Aelx Thanks for the info. I did not see any performance issue whilst reading node properties repeatedly. Just wanted to provide an optimized solution to the problem. I went ahead with using a simple map to get this done. Will try building a cache component with listener if any issues crop up during performance tests. Thanks.